# How to hide expand/collapse button in Virtual Treeview?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, virtualtreeview

I use VirtualStringTree (VST) to display data that is grouped, header-details. I need to have an option to allow user to expand, collapse headers to see details and in some cases I need to show data as static view, where they can't expand, collapse, only see full expanded tree:

Here is example when user can expand, collapse node with child node:

[image]

And here is example when I want to prevent user to expand/collapse node and always see all expanded (or whatever is shown):

[image]

in this test I control by 'Allow Expand/Collapse/ checkbox.

I prevent expand, collapse by adding:

```
Allowed:=CheckBox1.Checked;
```

into OnCollapsing/OnExpanding:

```
procedure TMainForm.VSTCollapsing(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; var Allowed: Boolean);
begin
  Allowed:=CheckBox1.Checked;
end;

procedure TMainForm.VSTExpanding(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; var Allowed: Boolean);
begin
  Allowed:=CheckBox1.Checked;
end;
```

I also show/hide TreeLines base on checkbox with

```
procedure TMainForm.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked then
    VST.TreeOptions.PaintOptions:=VST.TreeOptions.PaintOptions + [toShowTreeLines]
  else
    VST.TreeOptions.PaintOptions:=VST.TreeOptions.PaintOptions - [toShowTreeLines];
end;
```

**How can I hide this little plus sign when I want to prevent user to expand, collapse node. Any suggestions?**

---

**EDIT:**

To clear up the confusion with form icon, this is demo project from Virtual Treeivew 5 demo library. The form in IDE has Delphi XE7 icon, when running the project this old icon appear. Don't know why. Just wanted to make sure it is clear that I use XE7 and not any older Delphi versions, where the same solution might not apply.

In IDE the icon if as XE7 icon:

[image]

Comment: On a side-note, your question is tagged Delphi-xe7 yet the icon on your application appears as a very old version of Delphi...?

Comment: Didn't notice that at first...it's a demo project from Virtual Treeview 5 demo library, Minimal demo. IDE shows XE7 icon on Form, when running this old one creeps in.. don't know why.

Comment: Must be the old original `.res` file holding onto it.

Comment: I added an image of form icon in IDE, so there will be no confusion that I'm asking about XE7 or older Delphi version - in case the same solution is not for older versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The additional option you're looking for is `toShowButtons`. Use it in the same place you use `toShowTreeLines`.

The option is documented in *VirtualTrees.pas* in the declaration for `TVTPaintOption`:

```
    toShowButtons,             // Display collapse/expand buttons left to a node.
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rob Kennedy's answer, besides the option "toShowButtons", the other option that might be needed (for the top hierarchical level) is the option "toShowRoot"